# Limitar los tipos datos INT (solo que sean positivos)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas Tardes.

Estuve buscando en internet y no encontré nada.

Lo que quiero hacer es limitar todos los campos **INT** para que acepten solamente los positivos.
¿Hay alguna **función SQL** para realizar esto?

Se podría meter un IF que valide eso, pero no quiero que sea la solución.

Saludos

Comment: Agrega un constrain  `ALTER TABLE TuTabla ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Columna_Positivos
    CHECK (Columna > 0)`

Comment: @LuisFernando, sería bueno que tu comentario sea una respuesta...

Comment: Tiene que ser a nivel aplicación, o store procedure, porque sino te da una falsa sensación que ya insertaste y todo bien;
a la hora que das el insert un >=0 solucionarías muchas panoramas.

Comment: Tiene que ser a nivel aplicación, o store procedure, porque sino te da una falsa sensación que ya insertaste y todo bien;
a la hora que das el insert un >=0 solucionarías muchas panoramas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, para esta situación solo tienes que agregar un constraint a tu tabla, para validar siempre que sean positivos. Esta seria mas o menos el constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE TuTabla ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Columna_Positivos CHECK (Columna > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso valido a nivel de aplicación y ahí es donde valido que el dato ingresado sea positivo, lo hago con el plugin de jquery validate. A demás es de gran ayuda para validar cualquier campo y su tipo de dato.

Esa es la forma en que lo hago no quiere decir que sea la mejor forma, pero a mi me funciona y también se puede configurar el mensaje que se desea mostrar.